# Missing required param: interval - stripe/PHP

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I don't understand what going on my stripe code on PHP. I Certainly Definition interval but They are tell me "Missing required param: interval"

I just want to make a plan object.I want to create a plan object after creating a Customer object from the token received from ajax as below.

Is it necessary to obtain another php external resource from Composer etc. to make a plan?

## I made a plan as follows

```
  \Stripe\Plan::create();
  // \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_");
  $plan =  \Stripe\Plan::create(array(
    "amount" => 5000,
    "interval" => "month",
    "product" => array(
      "name" => "Emerald classic"
    ),
    "currency" => "jpy",
    "id" => "emerald-classic"
  ));
```

## All sources are this

```
<?php

  header("Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8");

  if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'])
     && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest')
  {
    if (isset($_POST['request']))
    {

      $name = $_POST['request'];
        require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
        \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_");

      \Stripe\Customer::create();
      $customer =  \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
        "description" => "taylor@example.com",
        "source" => "$name",
      ));

      //echo $customer;
      $customer_array = $customer->__toArray(true);
       foreach ($customer_array as $key => $value) {
        if ($key === "id") {
          $value_cus = $value;
        }
       }
       echo $value_cus;

      \Stripe\Plan::create();
      // \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_");
      $plan =  \Stripe\Plan::create(array(
        "amount" => 5000,
        "interval" => "month",
        "product" => array(
          "name" => "Emerald classic"
        ),
        "currency" => "jpy",
        "id" => "emerald-classic"
      ));

    };
  };

  ?>
```

Comment: I suspect the error is coming from this line: `\Stripe\Plan::create();` with no arguments.

Comment: You also have a similar error with `\Stripe\Customer::create();`. Why do you call these functions twice, first with no parameters?

Comment: That `foreach` loop can be replaced with `$value_cus = $customer_array['id']`.

Comment: You can also just use `$customer->id`.

Comment: Thank you help me !  your comments is so right !

Comment: I had the same error. I suspect about bad documentation... Thanks!